# Change VS code intellisense priority

Tags: reactjs, visual-studio-code

I want the specified item in the image below to be shown above all.
[image]

and my related settings:

```
"editor.snippetSuggestions": "top",
"emmet.showSuggestionsAsSnippets": false
```

Comment: Could you add and describe more about the details in your question. @Sajad Speed.

Comment: if you type `LinkT` it will be on top